# The specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Using 0 to many relationship for an entity property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm essentially trying to create an extension property on an entity named "Report", that can also be used in LINQ expressions.

Each Report entity has a 0 to many relationship with a table called ReportStatus, which will contain a history of all status updates for each Report.  New Reports will not yet contain an entry in this table (so I will just return empty string).  I want to be able to grab the *current* status code with ease (most recent entry in ReportStatus) for any given Report, as well as query Reports that match whatever status I'm wanting to filter on.  Due to the 0 to many relationship involved, it's getting over my head for a clean solution. If anyone can provide some guidance, it would be much appreciated.

The extension property as it stands right now:

```
public partial class Report
{
    public string CurrentStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return
                this.ReportStatus.Count == 0 ?
                "" :
                this.ReportStatus.OrderByDescending(r => r.ReportStatusDate).First()
                .StatusCode;
        }
    }
```

It gives the "The specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." on expressions such as  `_repository.Reports.Where(r => r.CurrentStatus == StatusCodes.Pending).ToList()`

Comment: It's giving you the error because LINQ-to-Entities has no idea how to translate the use of `CurrentStatus` since it's not actually a column in the database.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment above, you can't actually do that query in LINQ-to-Entities since `CurrentStatus` is not actually a column in the database. As such, you'll need to do the following as your query to get what you're asking for:

```
var pendingReports = _repository.Reports.Where(r => r.ReportStatus.Any() && 
                                               r.ReportStatus.OrderByDescending(s =>                        
                                                   s.ReportStatusDate).First().StatusCode == StatusCodes.Pending);
```

Comment: Thank you. I posted what I came up.

Answer (score 0):

Took a bit from IronMan84  Here's what I have now.

Made an extension class:

```
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Report> GetByStatus(
    this IQueryable<Report> query, string statusCode)
    {
        if (statusCode == "")
        {
            return query.Where(r => r.ReportStatus.Count == 0); // new reports, no status history
        }
        else
            return query.Where(r => r.ReportStatus.OrderByDescending(s =>
                   s.ReportStatusDate).FirstOrDefault().StatusCode.StatusCode1 == statusCode);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
         _repository.Reports.GetByStatus(StatusCode.Pending)ToList();
```

I still can use the CurrentStatus extension property shown in my question when just needing to peek at the status for a lone entity.  Thanks!